# Pygame Collision

Tags: python, collision-detection, pygame, sprite

How do I use `pygame.sprite.collide_rect`?

I want to make a game where if the girl is on ice she'll `slide` and when she's on ground (which will be another `sprite`) she won't `slide`. I was going to use the collision detection from pygame, but I'm not sure how.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: Aha! It turns out there is a friction coefficient, something I was unaware of. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306471/sliding-sprites

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If any of the answers was of any use to you it would be nice to upvote / accept them! :)

Comment: I usually don't mess with this, I check collision mathematically.  It is less complicated and usually allows your game to run faster.

Answer (score 2):

Could you post your code?

From what I gather, what you want is something like this:

```
if pygame.girl.colliderect(ice.rect):
     girl.slide()
elif pygame.girl.colliderect(ground.rect):
     girl.notslide()
```

Comment: If it's short you can just post it into the post itself, just prefix each line with 4 extra spaces, this tells StackOverflow to put it in a grey box and color certain words, like in my post above. If it's long you can put it in a pasting site, like http://pastebin.com/, and then post a link to the paste.

Comment: Also, for things like this, it's always good to look at the example code on the pygame website, especially http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html

Comment: I wrote some stuff in their that don't quite work yet, because I'm assuming those functions, so there may be errors and stuff---
game.py (main)
http://pastebin.com/DvaqHG9X
character.py (this is how I animate her)
http://pastebin.com/KWK5PvD2
And this is how she walks 
http://pastebin.com/uQkfNkV5

Comment: I'll look at it as soon as possible tomorrow, I need to go to bed right now.

Comment: Yeah, probably what you're going to want to do is include in check_bounds() a section saying:

    if pygame.girl.colliderect(ice.rect):
         slide = true;
    else:
         slide = false;

Then, in the walking section, you'll just include some section for momentum, something like "if the key stops being pressed, continue going until a certain amount of time has passed" (perhaps making the speed relative to the amount of time that has passed since the key was released). Does that work?

Comment: Aha! It turns out there is a friction coefficient, something I was unaware of. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306471/sliding-sprites

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to detect collision in pygame. Including rect, with groups of sprites, etc... In order to find one specific way of collision detection is just a matter of seeing the code you're working with. But with a simple sprite and rectangle you could just use:

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(girl_sprite, ice):
   slide()
else :
   continue_game()
```