# Sliding sprites

Tags: python, sprite, pygame, slide

I want my sprite to slide like he's on ice. So if he's on ground then he can walk normally, but when he touches ice he will slide until something stops him.
Does anyone know how one can do that?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you use a low value for the [friction coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Coefficient_of_friction) for ice.  Or at least lower than the value you're using for "walking normally."

Comment: I don't really have a friction coefficient for ice
Am I supposed to. I mean isn't there a way that the sprite can just slide. I mean I'm not writing anything complicated. If the sprite is on ground it'll walk and when it's not it'll slide. I'm doing a term project so I'm going for simple lol

Answer (score 1):

Manipulate the friction coefficients like the "[Sprite Movement Towards a Target](http://madcloudgames.googlecode.com/files/Sprite%20Movement%20Towards%20Target.zip)" example (modified below):

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ICE = 0.01
    LAND = 1.

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.normal_friction = .95 # friction while accelerating
        self.slowing_friction = .8 # friction while slowing down

    def update(self):
        # ...
        if self.dir: # if there is a direction to move

            if self.in_ice_region():
                surface_coefficient = Sprite.ICE
            else:
                surface_coefficient = Sprite.LAND

            if self.distance_check(self.dist): # if we need to slow down
                self.speedX += (self.dir[0] * (self.speed / 2)) # reduced speed
                self.speedY += (self.dir[1] * (self.speed / 2))
                self.speedX *= surface_coefficient * self.slowing_friction # increased friction
                self.speedY *= surface_coefficient * self.slowing_friction

            else: # if we need to go normal speed
                self.speedX += (self.dir[0] * self.speed) # calculate speed from direction to move and speed constant
                self.speedY += (self.dir[1] * self.speed)
                self.speedX *= surface_coefficient * self.normal_friction # apply friction
                self.speedY *= surface_coefficient * self.normal_friction

            self.trueX += self.speedX # store true x decimal values
            self.trueY += self.speedY
            self.rect.center = (round(self.trueX),round(self.trueY)) # apply values to sprite.center
```

Comment: wait, actually I want this person to slide (well more like skate) until it hits an object. This code is like a quick slide. I'm sorry I didn't properly look at it.

Comment: Change the coefficient value until it matches what you think it should be.  You have a ratio in mind (ice is twice as fast as land, three times, ten times) -- make the ratio between "ICE" and "LAND" correspond.

Comment: I don't know
I tried your code and my sprite isn't skating 
is there anyway to make a sprite move until it hits something
while only doing one keypress?

Comment: Yes, okay, I omitted collision detection.  You'll need to iterate through a list of objects and compare their coordinates to this Sprite's.